# SharePoint Project Management System

Tags: list, javascript, jquery

Unfortunately I have no code yet but I feel like this is the best place to ask the question to decide which approach to go down next.

I want to build a project management system. Currently a user can create a project which submits the details to aSharePoint list. On the home page I want it to be able show a button with the value of the name of the project and when this is opened it shows the details of this project.

Is this possible with JS and jQuery and can it recognise the user who created the project. I don't want others to have the button show. Unless they have their own project and then their button shows their project.

This be using a html page in a content editor

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it easily doable in SharePoint using some jquery stuff and html coding. For to show and hide the button in the home page, we can use the current logged in user attribute, based on that we can hide and show the project button.

Or, even you can try with out of the box list form. You can configure a list view webpart in the home page and there item URL would be project details link... this can be shown or hidden conditionally based on the user... this can be controlled by the JS link or script editor web part.

Comment: Thank you! Will let you know of any issues

Comment: Hi - if this has helped you, could you please mark this as answered, so that it will help to the upcoming visitors.